# rasterize_terrain DTM raster file write error

Tags: r, lidr

I am trying to create DTM rasters from a list of LAS files.

Code:

```
# Create a LAS catalog
LAS_List = readLAScatalog("path", recursive = TRUE)

# Create an output destination to store the DTM raster files
opt_output_files(LAS_list) <-  paste0("folder/{*}_dtm")

# Create a DTM using the TIN method
dtm_tin = rasterize_terrain(LAS_List, res = 1, algorithm = tin())
```

Now I am getting this error while running the `rasterize_terrain()` function:

```
Processing [=============>--------------]  52% (117/227) eta:  2hAn error occurred when processing the chunk 117. Try to load this chunk with:
 chunk <- readRDS("C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMxQWnM/chunk117.rds")
 las <- readLAS(chunk)
[writeRaster] file exists. You can use 'overwrite=TRUE' to overwrite it
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi JRR, yes kinda, so in my code's case will  `opt_output_files$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite = TRUE` will fix the issue? Or do I need to add anything else to the code too?

Comment: I did try `LAS_List_NE@opt_output_files$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite = TRUE` but got an error `Error in LAS_List@opt_output_files$drivers$Raster$param$overwrite = TRUE : 
  no slot of name "opt_output_files" for this object of class "LAScatalog"`

Comment: Just copy paste the answer provided in the linked question (change the name of the`LAScatalog`)

Comment: Well actually it may be rather `normalizedctg@output_options$drivers$SpatRaster$param$overwrite <- TRUE` because the output is with `terra` I guess

Comment: Yup that worked, cheers.